# Manipulating the DOM within an iFrame within Salesforce Lightning Communities

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

So I have a component that I need to hide in a community when certain conditions are met. Unfortunately I'll need to load the community page in an iFrame and then target the element and hide it when the conditions are met.

However:

iFrame.contentDocument.body.style...;

the body and or style is not being recognized and the property is null. 
I know this should work in js but is there a specific way to do this with the lightning/aura framework?

I already gave the iFrame an id and capture that in the controller.